# How to change angularjs variable from html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I set a value of some variable in javascript stored in angularjs controller when some html element is clicked. For example:

```
    angular.module('app',[])
        .controller('appController', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.onTheMove = null;
}
```

I want to set `onTheMove` to some value when `ng-click` is triggered from html.

```
<input type="radio" name="player" id="radio-1" ng-click="onTheMove = 1">
```

Comment: if you are not using "appController as" before the input tag, what you have looks fine too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to put it in the same controller:

```
  <div ng-controller="appController">
      <input type="radio" name="player" id="radio-1" ng-click="changeValue()">
    </div>
```

then create the change function

```
$scope.changeValue = function() {
    var val = $scope[propName];
    $scope.onTheMove = 1;
  };
```

or even easiear with ng-model

```
<div ng-controller="appController">
      <input type="radio" name="player" id="radio-1" ng-click="onTheMove" ng-value ="1">
    </div>
```